# How to provide path in flutter - path combine

Tags: dart, flutter

I am creating a quiz app in the Flutter for which I have collected some questions in CSV file. I want to store the CSV file in firebase and display questions into the app by reading from the CSV file. But just to check if the reading file is as simple as it should be, I tried to read a dummy file in this way:

```
new File('file.txt').readAsString().then((String contents) {
  print(contents);
});
```

from main.dart before returning the Widget. 
But i get this error:

```
`FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'file.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`
```

even though I have made a dummy 'file.txt' file in the same directory as 'main.dart'.

I tried doing './file.txt' and even the absolute path from windows explorer but none seem to work.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `path_provider` package allows you to access the temp and appDir directory

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

> ```
> Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
> String tempPath = tempDir.path;
>
> Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
> String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
> ```

You can use the `join()` method of https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path to concatenate paths in a platform dependent way, or just use string concatenation like

```
String filePath = '${appDocDir.path}/file.txt';

new File(filePath).readAsString().then((String contents) {
  print(contents);
});
```

Comment: Is that OS independent? I always thought that was the main reason you were supposed to use join operators in other languages like in Python's `os.path.join`

Comment: @Gerard it's exactly the purpose of this package to work around that limitation. The package currently only seems to support iOS and Android, so it probably does not work in the browser and probably also not on desktop (Windows, Linux, OSX) but for Desktop the Dart. For the temp directory you can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory/systemTemp.html. For joining paths, Dart/Flutter provides the https://pub.dev/packages/path package which takes platform delimiters into account.

Comment: this package did  not give download directory path

Comment: I use this and after search file, not found the file 
Where is this located?

Comment: how to get select download folder? FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

  if (result != null) {
    File downloadpath = File(result.files.single.path!);

    print(downloadpath);
    print("the file path is ");

Answer (score 8):

You can use join to safely join files or folders:

Example:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

    String fileName = Path.join('/storage/emulated/0/', 'MyFolder', 'file.txt');
```

Result:

fileName = '/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/file.txt'

Comment: Might be worth adding this as a reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-path_path/join.html

Comment: to select download path ? till folder names how? FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

  if (result != null) {
    File downloadpath = File(result.files.single.path!);

    print(downloadpath);
    print("the file path is ");

Comment: First I didn't believe I'd need a plugin for this, but trying to solve this with "native" Path led me to such a deep rabbit hole I just quit and installed the plugin.

Comment: It's very recommended to use join without the "/" because for example on Windows the / are backwards \ for paths. That's what you should separate every deep folder with a ","